# Searching through class array objects using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem that i want to add the UISearchController but search predicate not performing search because i my structure of code is like i have a Array of Class the item can first be fetched in the database and store in the singleton, after that i will get the object and by the class array through indexes here is my code

MasterViewController:

```
import UIKit

class MasterTableViewController: UITableViewController, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    var array: NSMutableArray! = NSMutableArray()

    var itemArray = Array<itemClass>()

    var filtereditemArray = [String]()
    var searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        self.tableView.reloadData()

        self.splitViewController!.delegate = self;
        self.splitViewController!.preferredDisplayMode = UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode.allVisible

        //Seach Result Controller
        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        self.searchController.definesPresentationContext = true
        self.searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar


    }


    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat{
        return 60
    }


    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if searchController.isActive{
            return filtereditemArray.count
        }
        else{
            return itemArray.count
        }
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)


        cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        cell.textLabel?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
        cell.textLabel?.numberOfLines = 3


        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "ChalkboardSE-Light", size: 14.0)


        if searchController.isActive {
            //let fra = filtereditemArray[indexPath.row]
            //cell.textLabel?.text = fra.title
        }
        else{
            let fd = itemArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.textLabel?.text = fd.title.uppercased()
        }

        return cell
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {

        self.filtereditemArray.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text!)

        let array = (itemClass as NSArray).filtered(using: searchPredicate)

        self.filtereditemArray = array as! [String]


        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("DidSelect index Path: \(indexPath.row)")
        //print("Filtered item Index: \(filtereditemArray[indexPath.row]))")

        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showDetail", sender: self)

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "showDetail" {

            let index = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow! as IndexPath

            let nav = segue.destination as! UINavigationController

            let vc = nav.viewControllers[0] as! DetailViewController

            if searchController.isActive {

        // pending

            }
            else{
                vc.selecteditemArray = [itemArray[index.row]]

            }
            self.tableView.deselectRow(at: index, animated: true)

        }

    }    

}
```

ItemClass:

```
import Foundation

class itemClass: NSObject{

    var id: String = String()
    var title: String = String()
    var category: String = String()

}
```

Comment: You've posted some requirements. You've posted a bunch of code. But you have not told what problem you are having. Please update your question to clearly indicate what help you need or what issue you are having with your code. Also, please narrow down your code to just the relevant parts associated with your issue.

Comment: You need to filter `itemArray` rather than `itemClass`. And use the same type for `itemArray` and `filtereditemArray`. That makes all delegate and data source methods much easier. Conforming to the naming convention that class names start with a capital letter avoids such silly errors. And finally use native Swift types and `filter` methods.

Comment: @vadian but i have to access all the itemClass element like that:

Comment: but how it's possible to filter via itemArray if i am doing then how they can access the internal elements of itemClass like title and please let me know how to apply that filter i am very thankful